# Connecting to different Databases for Every HTTP Rest call in Spring MVC

Tags: rest, http, spring-mvc, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm writing rest API to provide access to users to different SQL databases on the same DB server.

Example:

```
DB1: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9090/test1
DB2: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9090/test1 .....50 Databases.
```

Here is my scenario,

1. Every HTTP request from user has an associated ID.
2. Once the end point is called I have to read the ID and connect to the respective Database. For example: if ID=1 then I have to connect to DB1, if ID=2 then DB2.
3. After the response is sent I have to close the connection

Please let me know If I am unclear in any part of description. Suggestions/answers are appreciated.

Comment: instead of using the rest API to push to the different databases, use messaging services like JMS, so that whenever a message arrives based on the id you can activate particular listeners and push the message/data to the database. So, that you can remove the overhead on the server and also your application become more responsive.